# String in Razor is display wrong

Tags: string, razor

I have this razor syntax:

```
@Html.DisplayName("T.F.C")
```

However, when I run this, only the letter 'C' appears.  I have looked up escape characters and ASCII codes, and I can't seem to get it to work.

any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't `DisplayName()` take a string representing an object notation?  What is the structure of your model?  What are the runtime values?  I'd fully expect the value of `C` to be shown here, whatever `C` is in the model.

Comment: The data tip for DisplayName says that it takes a 'string expression' so I mean, I have other DisplayName()'s in my view and they render perfectly.. for example `@Html.DisplayName("Grand Total") displays 'Grand Total' in the view.. but @Html.DisplayName("T.F.C") only displays 'C'.. are you thinking of @Html.DisplayNameFor ?

Comment: According to the documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displaynameextensions.displayname) the argument is "An expression that identifies the object that contains the display name."  If you just want to display a static string, then why do you need server-side code *at all*?  Just put the value directly in the markup.  It's not really clear what you're trying to do, nor if you're even using `DisplayName()` for its intended purpose.

Comment: okay got it. that's why I was asking. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razor engine ignore all chars (or string) before last ".", Then 
If use `@Html.DisplayName("TF.C")`, You see "C".
If use `@Html.DisplayName("T.FC")`, You see "FC".

If you want display "T.F.C", you can use

```
@Html.Label("lblLabel","T.F.C")
```